# Radiobutton associated array php

Tags: php, arrays, radio-button

I've made an associative array with colors ('1'=>'Blue',...).
Now I have to make radiobuttons, each should represent a color? How can I do this with a foreach?

I've this code:

```
foreach($maanden as $key => $maand):?>
          <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $maand; ?></option>
            }
<?php endforeach?>
```

This only shows one radiobutton and no text after it.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Is it radiobutton or a select box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not the html code for radio-buttons but for a select-input.

Do radios like this:

```
<?php

foreach($maanden as $key => $maand): ?>
    <input type="radio" id="maanden_<?php echo $key; ?>" name="maanden[]" value="<?php echo $key; ?>" />
    <label for="maanden_<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $maand; ?></label>
<?php endforeach;

?>
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Then something is wrong with your array! Add the output of `var_dump($maanden);` to your question!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    foreach($maanden as $key => $maand):?>
        <input type="radio" name="color[]" value="<?php echo $key; ?>" id="color<?php echo $key; ?>"/><?php echo $maand;?><label for="color<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $maand; ?></label>
    <?php endforeach?>
```